# What is purpose of the single colon in setState Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Following proper standards of keeping this.state immutable

```
const name = this.refs.name.value; 
const names = [ ...this.state.names, name ]; 
//add new name to names array, and finally
this.setState({ names: names });
```

So I'm trying to understand what is setState trying to do here. Replace the old names array with the new updated names array?

Comment: *"Replace the old names array with the new updated names array?"*. Exactly.

Comment: check the doc: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: @dfsq ohh, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is there. 
The single colon in array sets the array value to the object.
facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

Well `{ names: names }` is just plain simple javascript object and what setState does is that the `state names` is being mutated to the new state which is the updated array.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing there is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...`. In ruby we have something very similar called splat operator. `names` becomes the result of concatenating all the elements of `this.state.names` and `name` into a new array. `setState({names: names})` then updates the internal state of the component with the new `names` property.

One of its uses it's spreading array to use it's elements as separate arguments for a function call.

```js
// Equivalent
console.log(...[1,2,3])
console.log(1,2,3)

// Usage in function definition
function asdf(qwer, ...uiop) {
  console.log('NICE', qwer, uiop)
}

asdf(1,2,3,4);

// a declarative replacement for this procedural code
function asdf2() {
  var qwer = arguments[0];
  var uiop = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.size);
  console.log('UGLY', qwer, uiop);
}

asdf2(1,2,3,4)
```

Beware JSX is a syxntax extension and may not have all the latest es5 and es6 features.